# How do I return the id of the element recent created - Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, response

I have to make an insert and the use that id for inserting another thing.

I would like to do something like this

```
var id_team;
$.ajax({
    url:    "/teams",
    type:   "POST",
    data:   {"authenticity_token": tokentag, team:{name:team, champeonship_id:champ}},
    success: function(response){
        id_team = response.id;
            alert(id_team);
        for(var i=1; i<14; i++){
            var rut = $('#rut'+i).val();
            var nom = $('#nom'+i).val();

            $.ajax({
              url:    "/players",
              type:   "POST",
              data:   {"authenticity_token": tokentag, player:{rut:rut, num:i, name:nom, team_id:id_team, champeonship_id:champ}},
              success: function(response){
                if(response.num==13){
                    alert('Saved');
                    window.location.assign("/create_team");
                }
              }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Action:

```
# POST /teams
# POST /teams.json
def create
  @team = Team.new(team_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @team.save
      format.html { redirect_to @team, notice: 'Team was successfully created.' }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
    end
  end
end
```

response.id now is undefined, what should i do?
I declare the variable outside and continue being undefined

Comment: Could you post the action handling the post?

Comment: Save `response.id` from inside the `success` function to a variable that exists outside of that function?

Comment: ok
I tried but didnt work

Comment: Have you actually coded it up? What happens after the action receives the post? Looking at your code the nesting of the format blocks is screwy, and there's a redirect happening which means your ajax success block I imagine will be steamrollered. What I don't get is why not just do the next part where you use the `id` to do extra processing on the server? You could use a PORO/Model method to help, or even an after create callback.

Comment: Could you give me an example? I don't know how to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make your create action in controller to send a json object with the id of the created team. And make the ajax post with dataType: 'json'

Edit:

```
# POST /teams
# POST /teams.json
def create
  @team = Team.new(team_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @team.save
      format.html { redirect_to @team, notice: 'Team was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: { team_id: @team.id} }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I have tried but it didn't work... How should i do it?

Comment: You can't do that with the code you posted because a) you don't have a javascript option in your respond_to block and b) you're redirecting on success, which will try to redirect you away from the page executing the AJAX call.

Comment: Ok, i understood that with another comment. I am asking how to do it, because i don't know much about ruby on rails. Could you post an example of code? Thanks

Comment: I have edited my answer with the json response from controller.

Answer (score 0):

Alex's comment is on the right track.  You want to use a [model callback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) and keep that logic out of the controller (Fat Model, Skinny Controller is the rails idiom).  It'll look something like this:

```
MyModel.rb
  after_create :create_team

  private
    def create_team
      # the logic you're trying to perform with that second ajax call belongs here
    end
end
```

As a second issue, you're missing a `format.js` block in your controller.  Without that, your controller has no idea what to do with the AJAX `POST` you're sending it.  [The docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to) for that provide good examples of working with javascript.